# Can I search posts which has TagA but does not have TagB?

Tags: support, search

We can search with tags as we all know like `[TagA]`. But sometimes I know that even though a question has `TagA` it will belong to a different context if it also has `TagB`.

Is there a way I can search for posts having one tag but not the other?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, just put a minus in front of any tags (or other search criteria) that you want to exclude.  From the [How do I search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page:

> To *exclude* results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with `-` in your query: `waffles -unicorns` finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while `[laurel] -[hardy]` includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.

As you can see this works for tags, so your search would be something like `[TagA] -[TagB]`.  There were [problems in the past with tag only searches messing up the excluded tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259915/hard-to-exclude-tags-in-search-for-new-nav), but I think they are resolved now.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is there also a way to set a filter with a combination under favorites?

Comment: @AndroidMechanic `intags:mine`