# Should it be possible to exclude a tag when searching?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I search for the `ruby` tag a lot of the time I get stuff about `ruby on rails` which I actually don't want. Should there be a way to specify tags you really really don't want to have? Not just one but many, if possible

Comment: Search *[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails]* ..

Comment: nice argument, though I'm interested is it referenced in the faq?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Yes. *"while [laurel] -[hardy] includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple.*"*

Comment: fair point; suggest post as duplicate and for possible deletion

Comment: From the Help Center (Which Bhargav Rao links): _"To exclude results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with `-` in your query: `waffles -unicorns` finds posts that mention tasty batter-based breakfasts without including mythical creatures, while `[laurel] -[hardy]` includes only posts pertaining to the first half of the classic comedy couple."_

Comment: Also [Can I search posts which has TagA but does not have TagB?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315109/can-i-search-posts-which-has-taga-but-does-not-have-tagb)

Comment: perhaps we need to make the info more prominent for newbies?

Comment: You seem to have edited this into a substantially different question. Are you now asking for a way to exclude multiple tags with less punctuation?

Comment: No really. The question remains I just extended it a bit based on feedback.

Comment: Same answers, same duplicate(s), then. `[tagiwant] -[donotwant] -[northis]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `-` (exclusion) and `*` (wildcard) operators to ignore a set of tags.  For example, if you want questions tagged with [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) but not tagged with any other tag beginning with the prefix `ruby-`, then you could use the search:

```
[ruby] -[ruby-*]
```

After submission, this gets expanded into the search

```
[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails] -[ruby-on-rails-3] -[ruby-on-rails-4] -[ruby-on-rails-3.2] -[ruby-on-rails-3.1] -[ruby-on-rails-plugins] -[ruby-on-rails-2] -[ruby-on-rails-4.2] -[ruby-1.9.3] -[ruby-on-rails-4.1] -[ruby-2.0] -[ruby-1.9] -[ruby-datamapper] -[ruby-1.9.2] -[ruby-1.8.7] -[ruby-2.1] -[ruby-debug] -[ruby-on-rails-5] -[ruby-c-extension] -[ruby-1.8]
```

[Results of the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby%20not%20ruby-on-rails%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3.2%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3.1%20not%20ruby-on-rails-plugins%20not%20ruby-on-rails-2%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4.2%20not%20ruby-1.9.3%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4.1%20not%20ruby-2.0%20not%20ruby-1.9%20not%20ruby-datamapper%20not%20ruby-1.9.2%20not%20ruby-1.8.7%20not%20ruby-2.1%20not%20ruby-debug%20not%20ruby-on-rails-5%20not%20ruby-c-extension%20not%20ruby-1.8?mode=all)

Comment: I mostly just click the 'tags' thing then click ```ruby```

Comment: Are you using a shell?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter shell?  It's the search box in the upper right corner.

Comment: Ah ha! I see...