# Search only for a tag or everything but the tag

Tags: support, search

Similar to

[image: tag]

I think we should also have ones that would:

- select all questions that has the tag/s in the search as their one and only tag ->Potentially, `[[tag]]`
- select all questions that doesn't have the tag/s in the search as any of their tags -> Potentially, `[!tag]`]

---

Comment: You can search for posts without the tag with `-[tag]`

Comment: Can you maybe add some examples for which searching for only the tag would be useful?

Comment: @I_love_vegetables does this mean you are unable to answer any of [ajax], [arrays] or [json] questions? (to take only the ones listed in the "Related Tags" list of [js]). Not willing to see **any** other tag seems pretty restrictive. Not willing to see [angularjs] or [php] I can understand, but we can already do that.

Comment: @Kaiido it also happens that *a lot* of questions tagged [angularjs] or [reactjs] or [vuejs] and even [jquery] are actually basic vanilla JS questions. Users love to tag any technology they might be using instead of what the question actually concerns.

Comment: @kaiido not really, thats why i said it will be nice to be able to see 2 or more tags only, for example if i wanted to search for javascript arrays i can do something like [js][arrays] to search for only js arrays. But yeah it probably wont help that much, im just saying it could be useful in some case

Comment: @VLAZ oh wait really? I didnt even notice that xD, i thought tags are mostly used to describe problems in that specific tech. Sorry my bad, im taking back my comments

Comment: @I_love_vegetables that's what tags *should* be used for. But that's not what a lot of users use them for. You can frequently see a question like "how do I sort an array in React" where the answer is nothing to do with React because array sorting is just plain JS. Many people seem to think that React/Vue/Angular are apparently *not* running JS but something else while asking for stuff that's only relevant to vanilla JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I search posts which has TagA but does not have TagB?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315109/can-i-search-posts-which-has-taga-but-does-not-have-tagb) This is basically what @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggested in the first comment. So far as I can tell, that's exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: @JeremyCaney yes, the first part.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I_love_vegetables's comment replying to Kaido seems to give a potential use case.